# Will a lateral followed by a forward pass be ruled illegal in future?

Tags: rules, american-football

In the 2015 AFC divisional round game between the Patriots and the Raven, Tom Brady threw a lateral pass to receiver Julian Edelman; [Edelman then threw a 51 yard touchdown pass to Danny Amendola](http://www.patriots.com/video/2015/01/10/highlight-q3-edelman-amendola-td). Will this kind of play be deemed illegal in the future?

Comment: Why do you believe this *might* be made illegal?

Comment: How could this be anything other than an opinion-based question - asking to predict the future?  More specifically asking if the NFL Rules Committee has taken it under consideration might be answerable, but not this as stands.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfectly legal play, and as far as I'm aware, there is no suggestion that this kind of play would be made illegal - what *would* you be making illegal anyway? A forward pass after a lateral? What about after a handoff?

Comment: One thing that may have been deemed illegal during that game was the [formation](http://www.businessinsider.com/nfl-banning-illegal-formation-patriots-used-in-playoffs-2015-3) the Patriots used on several plays, which is now considered illegal per the article. However, that is irrelevant to this play in question as said formation was not used.

Comment: @edmastermind29 interesting addition, thnx for the article

Comment: it's probably worth mentioning that a variation on this play has a name (flea flicker) and has been legal and used for a very long time.